# Folder shortcut in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a git repo in a folder that is inside multiple other folders.  When I want to use the command line for git, I have to do `cd /Desktop/.../.../.../.../repo_folder` to do git commands.  Is their any way that I can set a shortcut to a folder or get to a folder faster because having to type in a 70 character long path is not ideal

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Have a look at [this Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/bash-directory-shortcuts) article.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Unix usage are not programming per se and are better suited to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of Unix & Linux.  My bad.

Comment: make variable for that path? `gd="....." ;#gd=gitDir` then `cd "$gd"`, which can be in a function or alias. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/08/16/quickly-navigate-your-filesystem-from-the-command-line.html It allows to use something similar to a "bookmark" for paths.

Comment: I would recommend checking out ```zsh```. There's an awesome plugin called warpdrive (```wd```), that allows you to jump to bookmarked folders. ```zsh``` works well with Git, too, showing you the current branch, the state of the index, etc., all within the shell prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cdable_vars` option of `bash` that allows you to call `cd` with a variable name. If the argument passed to `cd` is not a directory, then it is assumed to be a variable name and the value of the variable is used as the destination directory.

Example of use: if you put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias show='cat ~/.dirs'
save () {
    here=`pwd`
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        name=`basename $here`
    elif (( $# > 1 )); then
        echo "usage: save [<name>]"
        return -1
    else
        name=$1
    fi
    sed -i -e "/^$name=/d" ~/.dirs
    echo "$name=\"$here\"" >> ~/.dirs
    source ~/.dirs
}
source ~/.dirs
shopt -s cdable_vars
```

Then, when your current directory is one that you want to remember, just type:

```
save my_dir
```

and the next time you want to go there, just type:

```
cd my_dir
```

As long there is no `my_dir` directory where you type it, it will bring you where you want. The `save` argument is optional. If you do not provide it the defined short hand will be the base name of the current directory:

```
cd /Desktop/../../../../repo_folder
save
```

will define `repo_folder` as the short hand for this directory.

The `~/.dirs` file contains your variable definitions for your favourite directories. You can edit it by hand, if you wish. These definitions are evaluated every time you launch a new `bash` shell. Beware they may overwrite others that you also need. If it is a problem, I advice you to chose unique short hands (`my_dir_repo_folder` instead of `repo_folder`). And remember the second pitfall, when you type:

```
cd foo
```

you can go either to the local sub-directory `foo` if there is one or to the directory for which you defined the `foo` short hand. And there is a third one: if you redefine a short hand, the previous one is overwritten. So, this trick is handy but somehow dangerous because when you `cd` you do not know any more if you are really where you want. Customizing your prompt to show the current path may be a good idea.

The `show` alias is just a way to list all currently defined short hands.

Answer (score 0):

Just set "start in" param in your bash shortcut properties and every time you run bash it will open your repo folder :)

[image]